# Confused regarding pre-processed table in KMP

Tags: string, algorithm

Looking over the KMP algorithm, and confused regarding a specific line in KMP which calculates the table of suffix-prefix counts.

algorithm kmp_table:
    input:
        an array of characters, W (the word to be analyzed)
        an array of integers, T (the table to be filled)
    output:
        nothing (but during operation, it populates the table)

```
define variables:
    an integer, pos ← 2 (the current position we are computing in T)
    an integer, cnd ← 0 (the zero-based index in W of the next 
    character of the current candidate substring)

(the first few values are fixed but different from what the algorithm 
might suggest)
let T[0] ← -1, T[1] ← 0

while pos is less than the length of W, do:
    (first case: the substring continues)
    if W[pos - 1] = W[cnd], 
      let cnd ← cnd + 1, T[pos] ← cnd, pos ← pos + 1

    (second case: it doesn't, but we can fall back)
    otherwise, if cnd > 0, let cnd ← T[cnd]

    (third case: we have run out of candidates.  Note cnd = 0)
    otherwise, let T[pos] ← 0, pos ← pos + 1
```

Above is taken straight from wikipedia. I'm a bit confused if `cnd > 0` why set `cnd := T[cnd]`, shouldn't cnd be reset back to 0 as if we're starting again?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `T[0] = -1` and so setting `cnd` to `T[cnd = 0] = -1` would amount to reading `W[cnd = -1]` on the next iteration and that's outside of the string. At least for that reason you need a special treatment for `cnd > 0` vs `cnd == 0`.

The real reason we compare `cnd` to 0 is that `T[cnd]` is supposed to give us the position in `W[]` to which to rewind when there's a partial string match to the left of `W[cnd]`. `T[0]`, however, can't be used for this purpose because there's nothing to the left of `W[0]`.

> why set cnd := T[cnd], shouldn't cnd be reset back to 0 as if we're starting again?

You are missing the whole point of the algorithm. If you restart at position 0 after a partial match, you are back at the naïve algorithm. `T[]` contains the rewind positions, which as you can see from the sample tables with `W[]` and `T[]` right below, aren't always 0. So, instead of going all the way back to position 0, you sometimes go to other positions and continue matching from there. And that's what makes the algorithm more scalable than the naïve one.